# AEM 6 Dynamic "parsys" with allowed Children

Tags: xml, aem, sightly

I have an "issue" with setting allowedChildren for dynamic generater parsys

div_list.html

```
<div class="row" data-sly-list="${[0,1,2,3,4]}">
    <sly data-sly-test.sxCol="${ '{0}{1}' @format=['col_sx_', itemList.index] }" />
    <sly data-sly-test.dxCol="${ '{0}{1}' @format=['col_dx_', itemList.index] }" />
<dt class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div data-sly-resource="${ @path=sxCol, resourceType='foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
    <!--/*<div data-sly-resource="${ @path=sxCol, resourceType='foundation/components/text'}"></div>*/-->
</dt>
<dd class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div data-sly-resource="${ @path=dxCol, resourceType='foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
    <!--/*<div data-sly-resource="${ @path=dxCol, resourceType='foundation/components/text'}"></div>*/-->
</dd>
```

the .content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
jcr:title="Tabella Div"
allowedChildren="[foundation/components/text]"
componentGroup="Credem Components"/>
```

My Issue it's that even giving to .content.xml properties of "allowedChildre" fundation/component/text and give to parent attribute of "cq:isContainer={boolean}true" it's fail to apply it..

And still allow my users to add any component.

Thanx for your time.
Andrea.

Comment: There is a bug at least in AEM6.0 and allowedChildren  is ignored. It announced fixed in   [6.0 Service Pack 2 Release Notes CQ-25520, CQ-27415][1] 
But it still exists in AEM6.1.
 Instead allowedChildren  you can setup design xml 
for more details take a look 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451560/aem6-component-allowedchildren-not-working

Comment: Okay, thx you very much for fast reply. I will take a look at your hint.

Good day/work